# Angular ui-router reloading entire App in ui-view

Tags: angularjs, express, pug, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a simple App using ui-router. When I load a page the first time or reload the current page, everything is fine. However when I click on a different page, the entire app reloads in my ui-view and I get a warning in the log: "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.". I am using Express, Jade and Angular.

I have the following structure:

```
public
   app
      frontPage
         frontPage.jade
      institution
         institution.jade
   app.js
   index.jade
server
   server.js
```

server.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/app/index.html');
});
```

app.js:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$stateProvider
    .state('frontPage', {
        url: '/app/frontPage/',
        templateUrl: 'frontPage.html'})

    .state('institution', {
        url: '/app/institution/',
        templateUrl: 'institution.html',
        controller: 'institutionCtrl'
    });
});
```

index.jade

```
#page-wrapper
    .row
        .col-lg-12
            <ui-view></ui-view>
```

frontPage.jade

```
block content
   h1 Page
   p Welcome
```

The above structure worked with ng-route, so I am quite lost why it keeps reloading the entire page when I switched to ui-router.

Comment: How look like your templates? The frontPage.html and institution.html files?

Comment: Your comment got my thinking about the url and the templateUrl properties. There was something wrong with them, when I changed them to  url: '/', templateUrl:  'app/frontPage/frontPage.html' and url: '/institution', templateUrl:  'app/institution/institution.html', everything worked! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had created a loop with the templates. When I changed them to this, it worked:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$stateProvider.state('frontPage', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl:  'app/frontPage/frontPage.html'
})
    .state('institution', {
        url: '/institution',
        templateUrl:  'app/institution/institution.html',
        controller: 'institutionCtrl'
    });
```

Comment: I also had the same thing but my template name was incorrect so it was loading the default template all over again. Just thought I'd add this here.

Comment: Same, sounds stupid but in my packaged project, the `templateUrl` didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for about an hour.  For me, the issue was that I had set the `html5mode requireBase` option to `false`.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

To fix this, I changed html5mode to this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Then set a base in my HTML, like this:

```
<base href="/"></base>
```